# Assign variable to multiple vectors in Clojure

Tags: clojure

The `clojure.contrib.sql` module has a `create-table` function that takes the table name and a list of specifications, like this:

```
(sql/create-table :services
                  [:id :serial "PRIMARY KEY"]
                  [:service_name :varchar "NOT NULL"]
                  [:pass_hash :varchar "NOT NULL"]
                  [:token :varchar "NOT NULL"])
```

If I'm reusing the same columns again and again, is there a way to define something like this?

```
(def same-columns 
                  [:id :serial "PRIMARY KEY"]
                  [:service_name :varchar "NOT NULL"]
                  [:pass_hash :varchar "NOT NULL"]
                  [:token :varchar "NOT NULL"])
```

When I tried running that in the REPL I got an error, because it passes too many arguments to `def`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably use [apply](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/apply) for this:

```
(def same-columns [[:id :serial "PRIMARY KEY"]
                   [:service_name :varchar "NOT NULL"]
                   [:pass_hash :varchar "NOT NULL"]
                   [:token :varchar "NOT NULL"]])

(apply sql/create-table 
       :services 
       same-columns)
```

If you have other columns you can add those as well:

```
(apply sql/create-table 
       :services
       [:some-column :varchar "NOT NULL"]
       same-columns)
```